# 1 database connection for 1 unit of work?

Tags: sql, database, connection, database-connection, connection-pooling

Let me start with an example of my "one unit of work":

I need to insert a transaction into the database. Along with that transaction, a couple unique codes are stored into a separate table, the foreign key being the transaction id. I have 4 database interactions: 1) get the next transaction id from a sequence; 2) insert the transaction; 3 & 4) insert 2 unique codes using the transaction id.

This is a multi-threaded Java application. Which route is best?

- each database interaction should get its own connection from the pool, commit and close it immediately after each step
- a single connection should be retrieved and used for each of the 4 steps, then commit once at the end and close the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked on a similar issue some time back using 'Akka' framework 'actors 'to help me with the multi threading part.

We settled with your second approach. Using single connection to do the work.
1) get the next transaction id from a sequence; 2) insert the transaction; 3 & 4) insert 2 unique codes using the transaction id.
Lets make this work atomic. If there is a connection failure in any of the four steps roll back that complete work.

Maintain an 'id' that will make sure this piece of work is started again. Id being updated only when all transactions in work complete.

If transactions are of different types then you can have different threads operating on them(each transaction type corresponds to separate work) with new db connections.